# OpenGL: Access violation reading location when calling glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to make a Minecraft-like game, and currently, I am stuck on getting chunks to work in a list. It works fine when I do it like this:

```
Chunk ch1(0, 0, 0);
ch1.fillVertices();
ch1.updateVBO();

Chunk ch2(0, 0, 17);
ch2.fillVertices();
ch2.updateVBO();

ch1.draw();
ch2.draw():
```

but I can't put them in a list and use them from there:

```
std::list<Chunk> chunks;
chunks.emplace_back(0, 0, 0);
chunks.emplace_back(16, 0, 0);

for (Chunk& chunk : chunks) {
    chunk.fillVertices();
    chunk.updateVBO();
}

for (Chunk& chunk : chunks) {
    chunk.draw();
}
```

because I get a "Access violation reading location" error message at `glDrawArrays`.
Here's the chunk code:

```
struct Chunk {
    
    Block* blocks = nullptr;
    unsigned int VAO = 0;
    unsigned int VBO = 0;
    float chunkPosX = 0, chunkPosY = 0, chunkPosZ = 0;
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    int chunkPosUniformLoc = 0;


    Chunk(float x = 0.0f, float y = 0.0f, float z = 0.0f) : chunkPosX(x), chunkPosY(y), chunkPosZ(z) {
        blocks = new Block[CHUNK_WIDTH * CHUNK_DEPTH * CHUNK_HEIGHT];
        if (!blocks)
            CLOG("Couldn't mallocate blocks!");
        
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glUseProgram(sp);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        chunkPosUniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(sp, "chunkPos");
    }

    void updateVBO() {
        if (vertices.size() != 0) {
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &(vertices[0]), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        }
    }

    void fillVertices() {
        vertices.clear();

        for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_HEIGHT; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_WIDTH; x++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_DEPTH; z++) {
                    unsigned int id = blocks[y * CHUNK_WIDTH * CHUNK_DEPTH + x * CHUNK_DEPTH + z].id;
                    BlockInfo bi = globalRe->getInfo(id);
                    if (blocks[y * CHUNK_WIDTH * CHUNK_DEPTH + x * CHUNK_WIDTH + z].id == BLOCKID::AIR)
                        continue;

                    if (z == 15 || !blocks[y * 16 * 16 + x * 16 + (z + 1)].isSolid()) { // Front
                        vertices.emplace_back( x, y, 1 + z, bi.textCoord[0][0].left, bi.textCoord[0][0].bottom );
                        vertices.emplace_back( 1 + x, y, 1 + z, bi.textCoord[0][0].right, bi.textCoord[0][0].bottom );
                        vertices.emplace_back( 1 + x, 1 + y, 1 + z, bi.textCoord[0][0].right, bi.textCoord[0][0].top );
                        vertices.emplace_back( 1 + x, 1 + y, 1 + z, bi.textCoord[0][0].right, bi.textCoord[0][0].top );
                        vertices.emplace_back( x, 1 + y, 1 + z, bi.textCoord[0][0].left, bi.textCoord[0][0].top );
                        vertices.emplace_back( x, y, 1 + z, bi.textCoord[0][0].left, bi.textCoord[0][0].bottom );
                    }
                    
                    // Other faces
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void draw() {
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glUseProgram(sp);
        glUniform3f(chunkPosUniformLoc, chunkPosX, chunkPosY, chunkPosZ);
        auto s = vertices.size();
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, s);
    }

    ~Chunk() {
        delete[] blocks;
    }

};
```

Using:

- GLAD
- GLFW
- OpenGL Core 4.3
- C++ 20
- Intel HD-Graphics 5500

I suspect that there's something wrong with my memory-management and there's corrupted memory somewhere although the Visual Studio Debugger doesn't say so. I just don't understand why it works as separate variables but not in a list.

Comment: What are the values of `CHUNK_...` constants (or not constants)? In `fillVertices`, you use in one places these variables for index calculations, in other - literal values 16 for same calculations. So, is `CHUNK_WIDTH == CHUNK_DEPTH == 16`? Also, note that you calculate `id` as local variable in the inner loop, and then don't reuse it in `if` statement. BTW, in that `if` statement it seems `x * CHUNK_WIDTH` should be `x * CHUNK_DEPTH` (then substitution to `id` is also obvious).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the other problems! After a lot of trying, the problem was fixed by adding a `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);` in `void updateVBO()`. But I still don't understand why. Shouldn't `glBindVertexArray(VAO);` also bind `VBO`?

Comment: `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);` *doesn't* bind/connect `vbo` as "array buffer" of the currently bound VAO. Instead, `glVertexAttribPointer` uses currently bound "array buffer" and stores within currently bound VAO an attribute description, which, among other things, refers to this "array buffer". Thus, when you do `glBindVertexArrays` in `updateVBO`, this doesn't change binding of `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and it contains some previous binding, so you use `vertices` to update not the buffer you intended, which likely causes memory problems (especially if `vertices` have different sizes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER isn't part of the VAO state. The VAO stores the buffer used for each attribute (the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER at the time glVertexAttribPointer was called), and the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER.

So your `updateVBO` is writing to the latest constructed chunk's VBO instead of writing to VBO of the chunk it's called on.

Fix: bind the VBO before `glBufferData`